# Compute the data dependency graph of a python program

Tags: python

I have a piece of python code:

```py
a0 = 1
a1 = 2
a2 = add(a0, a1)
a3 = [i + 1 for i in range(a2)]
```

I want to get the following [data-dependency graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dependency):

```py
{ "a0": [], "a1": [], "a2": ["a0", "a1"], "a3": ["a2"]}
```

I can use `locals()` to get the list of the local variables, but that's all I have for now. I could try to parse the AST but it seems to be a rabbit hole, since I'll need to handle every quirk of the AST.
Any ideas ?

**Usecase**: I'm trying to write a small DSL language, where the variables are task, representing long-running commands that need to be run. I'm using [doit](http://pydoit.org) but I find it cumbersome and hard to read to have to explicitly declare the dependencies while they are already visible in the code.

Comment: Does someone care explaining how this is too broad ? I've read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) but I'm still confused ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end `ast` module already have the very convenient "walk" method.

```py
import ast


def get_deps(code):
    body = ast.parse(code)
    _, statements = next(ast.iter_fields(body))

    full_graph = {
        assign.targets[0].id: [
            d.id for d in ast.walk(assign) if isinstance(d, ast.Name)
        ]
        for assign in statements
    }
    # full_graph also contains `range` and `i`. Keep only top levels var
    restricted = {}
    for var in full_graph:
        restricted[var] = [d for d in full_graph[var] if d in full_graph and d != var]
    return restricted


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = get_deps(
        """
a0 = 1
a1 = 2
a2 = add(a0, a1)
a3 = [i + 1 for i in range(a2)]
"""
    )

    assert d == {"a0": [], "a1": [], "a2": ["a0", "a1"], "a3": ["a2"]}, d
```